# mv: can't rename: No such file or directory. But directory exists

Tags: bash, mv

I am trying to rename a directory in a bash script. I get the following error (file path has been substituted):

```
mv: can't rename 'some/path': No such file or directory
```

This is the code I am using:

```
if [ -d some/path ]; then
  mv some/path other/path
fi
```

It makes no sense to make since I'm checking the existence of the directory beforehand. I also did a `find . -print` to list all files and directories in the current working directory and the desired directory definitely exists. I know about case sensitivity and triple checked all paths. Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Does the `other` directory exist?

Comment: Maybe an ACL problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was misleading. Since the destination path did not exists the command failed with an error.

This change worked for me:

```
if [ -d some/path ]; then
    mkdir -p other/path
    mv some/path/* other/path
fi
```